# How to unite several nodes in one big node using Tikz?

Tags: nodes, tikz-trees

I have to implement the Gomory-Hu-Algorithms which requires the reunion of several nodes to one node like it is shown [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/6/62/Gomory%E2%80%93Hu_Gp2.svg/799px-Gomory%E2%80%93Hu_Gp2.svg.png):

[image]

My code is quite simple since the example I want to implement is quite easy and only consists of a graph and a tree that is expanded in each iteration:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=3cm, every loop/.style={},
thick,main node/.style={circle,fill=green!50,draw,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries},
path/.style={circle, inner sep=2pt,fill=red!50, draw,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}]
\tikzstyle{edge_style} = [draw=orange, line width=2, ultra thick]

\node[main node] (b) {a,b,c,d,e};
\node[main node] (a) [below left = 1cm of b] {a};
\node[main node] (c) [right = 1.5cm of b] {c};
\node[main node] (f) [below  = 2cm of b] {f};
\node[main node](e)  [right = 1.5cm of f] {e};
\node[main node](d)  [below right = 1cm of c] {d};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

As you see till now I am only able to give names like a,b,c,d to a node but what I want is to get a node including nodes with names a,b,c,d.

Answer (score 7):

If all nodes you want to group are close, `fit` library which defines `fit` nodes can help you.

I don't understand the relation between the figure and your code, but following code produces the desired figure using a `fit` node.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit, shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, every loop/.style={},
thick,
main node/.style={circle,fill=green!50,draw,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries},
path/.style={circle, inner sep=2pt,fill=red!50, draw,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries},
edge_style/.style={draw=orange, line width=2, ultra thick}]

\node[main node] (1) {1};
\node[main node, below= 1mm of 1] (2) {2};
\node[main node, below left= -1mm and 3mm of 1] (0) {0};
\node[main node, below right=-1mm and 3mm of 1] (4) {4};

\node[ellipse, draw=red, fit=(0) (1) (2) (4), inner sep=-1mm] (all) {};

\node[main node, red, fill=gray, above right=5mm and 2cm of all] (3) {3};
\node[main node, blue, fill=gray, below right=5mm and 2cm of all] (5) {5};

\draw (all) -- node [above] {4} (3);
\draw[dashed] (all) -- node[below] {2} (5) -- node[right] {6} (3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried as you explained using the "fit" option. The problem is when I'm trying to add a second big node containing other nodes because then the second one is empty and the first still contains all nodes. It's the same code as above just with this difference:                                                       \node[ellipse, draw=red, fit=(a) (c) (e) (f), inner sep=0.5mm] (1) {};
 \node[ellipse, draw=green, fit=(b) (d), inner sep=0.5mm, above left=5mm and 2 cm of 1] (2) {};
 
 
 \draw (1) -- node [above] {4} (2);

Comment: @Gomory-Hu-user: Your second command means: "calculate an ellipse which size is enough to contain nodes b and d and draw it in green at a position 5mm above and 2cm left of node 1". If you delete `above left ...` option the ellipse will surround nodes b and d.

Comment: If I delete the above left ... option I get two overlaped ellipses and the second one is still empty: \node[ellipse, draw=red, fit=(a) (c) (e) (f), inner sep=0.5mm] (1) {}; \node[ellipse, draw=green, fit=(b) (d), inner sep=0.5mm, left=5mm of 1] (2) {}; or am I still forgetting something? –

Comment: @Gomory-Hu-user: All `fit` nodes are empty, they are just a rectangles, circles or ellipses which are drawn with dimensions determined by previously drawn nodes. So, `\node[ellipse, draw=green, fit=(b) (d), inner sep=0.5mm, left=5mm of 1] (2) {};` draws a node big enough to encompass nodes `b` and `d`. This node is moved to `left=5mm of 1`. ONLY THIS NODE (en empty ellipse) is moved, nodes `b` and `d` remain in their original position (`fit`doesn't work as a `copy+paste`). If you want that nodes `b` and `d` appear inside node `2`, you should drawn them again in their new position.

Answer (score 4):

Almost the same as Ignasi answer ... :). I assume, that positions of nodes 0, 1, 2 and 4 is not important and that can lie on circle and that line around it is not necessary to be ellipse:

[image]

For above picture I try to made short code as possible in which I use only needed styles:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz,preview]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning}
    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, thick,
 node distance = 7mm and 22mm,
MN/.style args = {#1/#2}{circle,
                         draw=#1,
                         fill=#2,
                         inner sep=0.5mm, outer sep=0mm,
                         font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries},
    MN/.default = black/white
                    ]

\foreach \i[count=\ix from 0] in {0,1,2,4}
    \node (n\i) [MN,node distance=0mm] at ({90*\ix}:4.2mm) {\i};
\node (a)   [MN=red/none,fit=(n0) (n2)] {};
\node (n3)  [MN=red/gray!50,
             above right=of a] {3};
\node (n5)  [MN=blue/gray!50,
             below right=of a] {5};
\draw (a) -- node {4} (n3);
\draw[dashed]   (n3) -- node {6} (n5)
                (n5) -- node {3} (a);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```